# Makefile + Pylint + Find files - recipe for target 'lint' failed

Tags: makefile, pylint

Would you know where is my syntax / code error in my following Makefile please ?

```
.PHONY: lint

PYTHON_SCRIPTS_LIST := $(shell find . -type f -name "*.py")
PYTHON ?= python

lint:
    $(PYTHON) -m pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc $(PYTHON_SCRIPTS_LIST)
```

When I execute `make lint`, it works well but returns :

```
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'lint' failed
make: *** [lint] Error 30
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Error 30 could be a normal pylint run with error, warning, convention and refactor messages. Did you get an output ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your makefile.  This error means the python invocation exited with an error code of 30.  Following 50 years of tradition, make considers that any program that exits with a 0 exit code worked and any program that exits with a non-0 exit code (including 30) failed.  Before the messages you showed us here, pylint printed out some messages explaining why it failed.  You should address those, then make won't fail.  Or if you don't want make to fail when pylint fails, you can prefix the `$(PYTHON) ...` line with a dash `-` which tells make to ignore the error code.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas ==> Yes Pylint works actually normally and returns me even the rating of my code "Your code has been rated at 9.64/10 (previous run: 9.64/10, +0.00)" but then it shows me this Makefile error.

Comment: @MadScientist ==> Thank you for your help. I actually tried both ```-$(PYTHON) -m pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc $(PYTHON_SCRIPTS_LIST)``` and ```- $(PYTHON) -m pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc $(PYTHON_SCRIPTS_LIST)``` but it didn't work, same Makefile error. Would you have another idea please ?

Comment: It doesn't give the same error.  It will instead say `[lint] Error 30 (ignored)`.  That's different than what it did before.  It means that make is ignoring that error.  If you want it to not print the message at all then you have to either fix all your pylint issues so that pylint doesn't show an error, or you can try adding `|| true` to the _end_ of that pylint recipe: `$(PYTHON) -m pylint ... || true`  That will always have the recipe exit with a success code regardless of what python exits with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clarifying in comments, it seems that you're running pylint and it still emits message. pylint will exit with error code 0 only if there isn't any message emitted. So you can either:

- Fix all the messages
- Disable all the messages
- Fix some message and disable some of them
- Stop caring about the makefile output if you only want to run pylint
- Catch the exit code in the makefile command by adding `|| true` after the command ( `$(PYTHON) -m pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc $(PYTHON_SCRIPTS_LIST) || true`)
- Use pylint [`exit-zero` option](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html) ( `$(PYTHON) -m pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc $(PYTHON_SCRIPTS_LIST) --exit-zero`)